# Installing SQL Server on Centos 7.3 using Docker

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, centos7

I'm having some trouble installing SQL server in a fresh centos 7.3 in a virtual server in Soyoustart using docker.

After running  the install comand

```
sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=xxxxx" -p 1433:1433 -v /var/opt/mssql:/var/opt/mssql -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

I look in the messages log file and I found this and im unable to login.

```
Apr 18 12:36:36 Demo journal: Configuring Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R)...

Apr 18 12:36:36 Demo journal: sqlservr: File.cpp:972: virtual SystemStatus File::Map(void *, ssize_t, int, int, off_t, void *&, ssize_t &): Assertion `mappedBase == address' failed.

Apr 18 12:36:36 Demo journal: ls: cannot access '/proc/16/smaps': No such file or directory

Apr 18 12:36:36 Demo journal: cat: /proc/16/sched: No such file or directory

Apr 18 12:36:37 Demo journal: dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted

Apr 18 12:36:37 Demo journal: No journal files were found.

Apr 18 12:36:37 Demo journal: No journal files were found.

Apr 18 12:36:37 Demo journal: ls: cannot access '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog*': No such file or directory

Apr 18 12:36:37 Demo journal: ls: cannot access '/var/opt/mssql/log/exception.log': No such file or directory

Apr 18 12:36:37 Demo journal: ls: cannot access '/var/opt/mssql/log/SQLDu*.txt': No such file or directory

Apr 18 12:36:37 Demo journal: ls: cannot access '/var/opt/mssql/log/SQLDu*.mdmp': No such file or directory

Apr 18 12:36:37 Demo journal: ls: cannot access '/var/opt/mssql/log/system_health*': No such file or directory

Apr 18 12:36:37 Demo journal: Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R) setup failed with error code 1. Please check the setup log in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information.
```

Log file
/var/opt/mssql/log/setup-20170418-103636.log

```
Dump control values set to default.  Behavior controlled with /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf

===============================================

              Mini dump type: miniplus (2)

Capturing mini and full dump: true

===============================================

Capturing core dump and information for sqlservr (pid 16)...

Capturing dump with paldumper

Attempt to capture dump with paldumper failed.  Reference core.sqlservr.16.temp/log/debug.log for details

Capturing dump with gdb

SQL Log Directory /var/opt/mssql/log

Packaging core dump and information into compressed files.

Core dump and information will be written to /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.04_18_2017_10_36_36.16 and logs in /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.04_18_2017_10_36_36.16.log
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: this **seems** to solve the issue:https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/12#issuecomment-280212357

Comment: Thanks for the advice but didn't work for me.

Comment: Is the server running on shared resources? Do you know the specifications of the instance you're trying to run on?